# Qt TabWidget Tab rename in runtime

Tags: c++, qt, computer-science, qt-designer

i am using C++ with visual Studio 2010 along with Qt;

Everything is done through code. I do not have access to Qt Designer.

My question is:

I am working on an opensource software knows as "EasyPaint".
I am trying to implement a tab Rename ( when a user Double clicks on the tab, he can Rename it in runtime)

For that, i used an eventFilter :

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event){
    if (obj == mTabWidget &&
        event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonDblClick) {

        // query and set tab(s) names
        QTabWidget *tab = qobject_cast<QTabWidget *>(obj);
        if(tab)
        {
            QDialog dlg;
            QVBoxLayout la(&dlg);
            QLineEdit ed;
            la.addWidget(&ed);
            QDialogButtonBox bb(QDialogButtonBox::Ok | QDialogButtonBox::Cancel);
            la.addWidget(&bb);
            dlg.setLayout(&la);
            if(dlg.exec() == QDialog::Accepted)
            {
                tab->setTabText(0, ed.text());
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    // Standard event processing
    return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
}
```

After implementing the eventFilter, i tried to call install it on the tab like so :

```
void MainWindow::initializeTabWidget() {
mTabWidget = new QTabWidget();
mTabWidget->setUsesScrollButtons(true);
mTabWidget->setTabsClosable(true);
mTabWidget->setMovable(true);
connect(mTabWidget, SIGNAL(currentChanged(int)), this, SLOT(activateTab(int)));
connect(mTabWidget, SIGNAL(currentChanged(int)), this, SLOT(enableActions(int)));
connect(mTabWidget, SIGNAL(tabCloseRequested(int)), this, SLOT(closeTab(int)));
setCentralWidget(mTabWidget);
mTabWidget->installEventFilter(this);
```

}

you can find the `installEventFilter` on the last line of the previous function.

The program runs fine. no errors what so ever. However I am not being able to change the tab's name when double clicking.

for this line of code :

`mTabWidget->installEventFilter(this);`

I also tried using `installEventFilter(mtabWidget)` instead, with no luck

thank you for your help.

Comment: Did the renaming dialog show up after double-clicking?

Comment: no the dialog isnt showing up. @Tay2510

Comment: Did you debug your event filter to see if it is called at all?

Comment: Do you expect it to act when you double click on tab bar?

Comment: @ Bowdzone. What i did, i inserted a breakpoint on the EventFilter Function. When mTabWidget->installEventFilter(this) is uncommented, the software breaks before it runs. ( it doesnt run, the break point breaks it) , when i comment it ( not part of the code anymore) , the program runs fine with a breakpoint on eventfilter function

Comment: @Nejat Yes, i do, user must double click on the tab ( which by default has a title of "Untitled image" )

Answer (score 2):

If you want to capture the event when you double click on tab bar, you should install the event filter on the `QTabBar` of the tab widget. But `QTabWidget::tabBar()` is protected and you can not access it. The solution is to derive a class from `QTabWidget` and implement a public function which returns a pointer to `QTabBar` :

```
#include <QTabBar>
#include <QTabWidget>


class customTab: public QTabWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    customTab(QObject *parent = 0) :
    QTabWidget((QWidget *)parent)
    {
    }
    ~customTab(){}

    QTabBar *getTabBar()
    {
        return this->tabBar();
    } 
};
```

Now you can install event filter on the tab bar (`mTabWidget` is an instance of `customTab`) :

```
mTabWidget->getTabBar()->installEventFilter(this);
```

Your event filter should be like :

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event){
    if (obj == mTabWidget->getTabBar() &&
        event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonDblClick) {

        ...
```

Comment: If you subclass the `QTabWidget` anyway you could also handle the doubleclick-rename here and not in the `MainWindow`. Seems like a cleaner solution to me

Comment: @Bowdzone You are right. It's an other way to implement it which seems good.

Comment: @Bowdzone
The code above is not working for me, i created a new class, and implemented the class cutomTab..(the first block of code above) in the.h file, my .cpp is empty.  now when i go back to MainWindow.cpp and try to write mTabWidget->getTabBar(), it doesnt let met , it cant find getTabBar..

Comment: Did you make sure that the tabwidget you use is your custom tab widget and not still the default `QTabWidget`?

Comment: @AndreFarah Your class member `mTabWidget` should by of type `customTab`. You should have `customTab mTabWidget;` in your `MainWindow.h`.

Comment: yes i have changed that in the .h 
    // QTabWidget *mTabWidget;   <--- REMOVED
    customTab mTabWidget;     <--- ADDED

Comment: Also in the MainWindow.cpp File  If you look at my initial question, the second block of code, where i showed the initializeTab function.
I removed mTabWidget= new QTabWdiget() and added customTab mTabWidget;

Comment: UPDATE: I used a Pointer in the MainWindow.h for the customTab  like so : customTab *mTabWidget; then i changed the mTabWidget to Type customTab, when i run it, the program crashes. IT says Easypaint has stopped working @Bowdzone

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you using a simple connection to QTabWidget::tabBarDoubleClicked() slot. It's already there, you don't need an event filter at all. It would result in a much simpler and cleaner implementation:

```
connect(myTabWidget, &QTabWidget::tabBarDoubleClicked,
        myWindow, &MyWindow::onTabBarDoubleClicked);
```

(...)

```
void MyWindow::onTabBarDoubleClicked(int index)
{
    // Code to rename the index-th tab here

    // Example:
    myTabWidget->setTabText(index, "some nice text");
}
```

Comment: There is no Such Signal for QTabWidget, this is the error i get on runtime, and also it is not in Qt Documentations.

Comment: Please, can you specify which Qt version are you using? The signal have been introduced since Qt 5.2,

Comment: i am using 4.8.  is there an alternative for this ?

Comment: Sorry not having asked you about version in the first place. I would take the subclassing route int his case, probably adding a similar kind of signal myself.

Comment: can you please take a look at the solution below, from Nejat. I tried doing that, ( i first implemented the class inside of MainWindow.cpp , but it did not work, so i added a new customTab.h file, and copied what Nejat had there,  then i went back to MainWindow, and there when i was trying to write the event filter that Nejat offered, i was getting a red underlining on mTabWidget->getTabBar()-> ( mTabWidget does not have in the list getTabBar() )